# Java 9 modularity vs Microservices?

Tags: java, microservices

What is the difference between these two??

With the help of Microservices we can separate out the large code base into small manageable pieces(microservices), and same can be achieved with java 9's modularity feature.

Comment: They might have similar aims in different contexts. So does a pizza cutter, but a pizza cutter is not the same as microservices.

Comment: These are very different things.  A module can contain many microservices;  a microservice can consist of many modules.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 9 you can achieve modularity of your code, microservices are independently deployable components.

To be independently deployable, the code must be modular, of course. Java 9 offers one way to do this, but you can achieve the same with Maven modules for example.

It's a good practice to make your code modular, even you don’t need or want to deploy components independently. It makes your code maintainable and cheaper in longer term.